# Volume on host - permission denied for Postgres (Mac OS)

Tags: docker

I am starting Postgresql image with following volume

```
/Users/me/Desktop/volumes/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

According to docker docs it should work as docker should have access to `/Users` directory on Mac OS. After creating & runing container I can see
that empty directory `/Users/me/Desktop/volumes/postgresql/data` is created however Postgres does not start and show these lines in log:

```
could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/global": Permission denied
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your directory belongs to a different User then the user, that the User that executes the container.

Could you change your directory like that for a start.

```
chmod 777 /Users/me/Desktop/volumes/postgresql/data
```

If you can start your container with this setting, then this missing permissions are the root cause.

You could then try to start your container with

```
run -u uid ...
```

and specify the userid of your user on macos.
You have to create the user in boot2docker too, i.e.

```
boot2docker ssh
sudo sh
adduser <anyuserid> -u <your uid>
```

Comment: Have the same problem with latest docker and docker-machine on MacOS. What is the right way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

What I done was the workaround by creating the folder inside the Virtual Box.

Set your docker-compose.yml postgresql folder:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/volumes/postgresql/data
```

to

```
/root/data
```

Enter at the Docker at Virtual Box and create the data folder